# Any suggestions on what to do ... Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I am getting this error on the "DecryptStringAES" here is the code ... the line in error is

```
plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadtoEnd();
```

here is the rest of the code:

```
 *public string EncryptStringAES(string plainText, int AccountID = 0)
    {
        string sharedSecret = "";

        AccountID = (AccountID > 0) ? AccountID : SessionVars.Current.varAccountID;
        sharedSecret = "#c3x%" + AccountID + "n^/]R";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        string outStr = null;                       // Encrypted string to return
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;              // RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.

        try
        {
            // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

            // Create a RijndaelManaged object
            aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
            aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
            aesAlg.KeySize = 256;
            aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
            SessionVars.Current.varEncryptKey = aesAlg.Key;
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // prepend the IV
                msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
                msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                }
                outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            if (aesAlg != null)
                aesAlg.Clear();
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return outStr;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypt the given string.  Assumes the string was encrypted using 
    /// EncryptStringAES(), using an identical sharedSecret.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText">The text to decrypt.</param>
    /// <param name="sharedSecret">A password used to generate a key for decryption.</param>
    public string DecryptStringAES(string cipherText, int AccountID = 0)
    {
        string sharedSecret = "";

        AccountID = (AccountID > 0) ? AccountID : SessionVars.Current.varAccountID;
        sharedSecret = "#c3x%" + AccountID + "n^/]R";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

        // Declare the RijndaelManaged object
        // used to decrypt the data.
        RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        try
        {
            // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

            // Create the streams used for decryption. 
            string dummyData = cipherText.Trim().Replace(" ", "+");
            if (dummyData.Length % 4 > 0)
                dummyData = dummyData.PadRight(dummyData.Length + 4 - dummyData.Length % 4, '=');
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dummyData);
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                // Create a RijndaelManaged object
                // with the specified key and IV.
                aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
                aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
                aesAlg.KeySize = 256;
                aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
                //  aesAlg.Key = SessionVars.Current.varEncryptKey;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                // Get the initialization vector from the encrypted stream
                aesAlg.IV = ReadByteArray(msDecrypt);
                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {



                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.

                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
            if (aesAlg != null)
                aesAlg.Clear();
        }

        return plaintext;
    }

    private static byte[] ReadByteArray(Stream s)
    {
        byte[] rawLength = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        if (s.Read(rawLength, 0, rawLength.Length) != rawLength.Length)
        {
            throw new SystemException("Stream did not contain properly formatted byte array");
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(rawLength, 0)];
        if (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != buffer.Length)
        {
            throw new SystemException("Did not read byte array properly");
        }

        return buffer;
    }*
```

I have tried a few different things... but the error "Padding in invalid and cannot be removed" keeps coming up. This code was working fine, but then all of the sudden it started errorring out.

Comment: Try decrypting in pure binary mode (without `StreamReader`) and with no padding specified — that way you will see whether the ciphertext decrypts correctly, and what do padding bytes actually contain. Be also aware that `BitConverter` behavior is platform-dependent.

Comment: Thank you Anton I will try that, but I do think I figured out the issue.

Comment: Well, at least I tried your code without any modifications (just set some default values for `_salt`, `varAccountID` and `varEncryptKey`), and it worked just fine for several input strings of different length. To my surprise, `_salt` was allowed to be smaller than 128 bits (16 bytes), but still no less than 64 bits (8 bytes).

Comment: yeah ... the problem was because of the key value. in debug it appeared that I was feeding both processes the correct key, but apparently I was not. so I changed that process in and it worked.

Comment: @Paul I don't think the question can be answered with the code that you provided. Either add the missing code + provide your own answer *or* delete the whole question.

Comment: The salt value is just an input to the HMAC (and thus hash) function that is within the PBKDF2 algorithm implemented by `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`. So the length actually doesn't matter, it's just that 64 to 128 bytes is a sensible security margin. It's not like the IV that needs to be precisely one block for CBC mode encryption.